# returning an object from a method dealing with Linked List nodes

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

i'm writing a method using linked list to delete even number indexes from the list (i'm not using `List<object> list = new LinkedList<object>()` <--- i know this is kinda easier.., i'm implementing node class in this problem (which i'm really confused at right now.)

Well, the problem tells me to delete the even number indexes from a `List`, and return a new `List`. But i don't know what to do here (this method is in `LinkedIntList` class that also contains `ListNode` class)? And please check my code if it's right or what i can do to improve.  Thanks.

```
public ????????? removeEvens() {
    ListNode current = front;
    while(current.next!= null) {
        current = current.next.next;
    }
    return ???????????;
}
```

**EDIT**: i've tried `NodeList` but it still give me an error so i guess i'll post a pic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to return a new List, the return type should be a ListNode or a LinkedList.

```
public ListNode removeEvens(){
  ListNode current = front;

   //Since we are setting current's next to current.next.next, we need to make
   //sure that we don't get a null point exception. 
   while(current.next!=null){ 

    //removes all event nodes.
    current.next = current.next.next;
    current = current.next;
  }

  return current;
}
```

A LinkedList can be represented by a ListNode. If you want to return a LinkedList, simply change the return type of the function and return a new LinkedList with the current list node passed into the constructor.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort.  It still give me error though, i uploaded a picture on main post. Please take a look again.

Comment: Hello. That is because a ListNode is not a LinkedIntList. Did you try: ListNode actualEvens = removeEvens(); ?

Comment: I should warn you that this method does not return a NEW list. Since you are changing the references of the list nodes in current, the change will affect your original list. Therefore, you need to make a new front listnode with a copy constructor.

Comment: Hi i still have no idea what to put in my method header, and the return type. Because this problem is from a website and i write the method from the website too.

Comment: The function above returns a ListNode. Therefore, you have to set a ListNode equal to it.

Comment: This is a link to the website.  http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/practiceit/problem.jsp?category=Building+Java+Programs%2C+3rd+edition%2FBJP3+Chapter+16&problem=bjp3-16-e16-removeEvens